# Shortcut target path via VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying correct a shortcut target path for MS Access using a registry key and the file location on a network share.

App Path of MS Access via Registry:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office 15\MSACCESS.EXE
```

Network location of Database:

```
\\H00t0000vfsrv03\Share\Folder\Database.MDB
```

I can not get shortcut path to take, gives me

> Invalid procedure call or argument, 800A0005.

Code:

```
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

ServerPath = Chr(32) & "\\H00t0000vfsrv03\Share\Folder\Database.MDB"

If Not WSHShell Is Nothing Then
    DesktopPath = WSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    InstallRoot = Chr(34) & WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MSACCESS.EXE\") & Chr(34)
    TargetName  = InstallRoot & ServerPath
    WScript.Echo TargetName

    CommandName = TargetName
    wscript.echo CommandName
    Set MyShortcut = WSHShell.CreateShortCut(DesktopPath & "\Shorcut" & ".lnk")
    MyShortcut.TargetPath = TargetName
    WScript.Echo MyShortcut.TargetPath
    MyShortcut.WindowStyle = 1
    MyShortcut.Arguments = ""
    MyShortcut.Save
    Set MyShortcut = Nothing
End If
```

I have added

```
shortcut.Targetpath = """C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office 15\MSACCESS.EXE"" H00t0000vfsrv03\Share\Folder\Database.MDB"
```

and this last line does not work.  The App Path can vary depending on the MS Access Office version.  Trying to get the correct number of double quotes so that the shortcut can be mapped.

Answer (score 0):

Although the `.MDB` extension is probably associated to MsAccess, I understand you want a shortcut to explicitely use the installed MsAccess.exe to avoid getting into trouble where a user has changed this to some other application.

When creating a shortcut like this, you need to fill in the correct values for the different properties.

The shortcuts **TargetPath** should be `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\Root\Office 15\MSACCESS.EXE"`
The shortcuts **Arguments**  should be `"\\H00t0000vfsrv03\Share\Folder\Database.MDB"`

As you are doing it now, you are trying to set the `TargetPath` to

```
"C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE" \\H00t0000vfsrv03\Share\Folder\Database.MDB
```

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Dim WSHShell
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

If Not WSHShell Is Nothing Then
    Dim ServerPath, DesktopPath, InstallRoot, MyShortcut
    ServerPath  = Chr(34) & "\\H00t0000vfsrv03\Share\Folder\Database.MDB" & Chr(34)
    DesktopPath = WSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")

    'get the long path for MSACCESS.EXE
    InstallRoot = WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\MSACCESS.EXE\Path")
    'there SHOULD be a backslash at the end, but check anyway
    If Right(InstallRoot, 1) <> "\" Then InstallRoot = InstallRoot & "\"
    'add "MSACCESS.EXE" to this path and surround with double quotes
    InstallRoot = Chr(34) & InstallRoot & "MSACCESS.EXE" & Chr(34)

    'create the shortcut on the desktop
    Set MyShortcut = WSHShell.CreateShortCut(DesktopPath & "\ShorcutToDatabase" & ".lnk")
    MyShortcut.TargetPath = InstallRoot
    MyShortcut.WindowStyle = 1
    MyShortcut.Arguments = ServerPath
    MyShortcut.Save

    Set MyShortcut = Nothing
    Set WSHShell = Nothing
End if
```